# Any python package that can be used to handle METEOR RADAR data sets?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-analysis, physics, atmosphere

Is there any existing python package that can be used to handle METEOR RADAR data sets which are in **.hwd file format**?

I want to work on atmoshpereic science project on tide analysis in the MLT region using python.So, the source of the data is METEOR RADAR which stores data in .hwd file format(height width depth).

I tried searching the internet for specific packages that could help me file handle **.hwd files** but ended up finding **no packages or libraries** that are currently active.

Could you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: import magic; print(magic.from_file('aaa.hwd'))

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out!
There is **no need for external packages** to work on **hwd** files in python.

**hwd** files stand for **Horizontal Wind Data** files. So, METEOR radar stores data in hwd file format, which can be treated **as a normal text(.txt) file** for file handling in python.